# Filter and Find from in-memory data sets

Tags: .net, indexing, in-memory

I have several medium-sized data sets in-memory that I need to be able to filter and find information from quickly. The data sets are small enough that I don't want to take the performance hit of going to a database every time I need an entry but large enough that I really need to index the data somehow.

Currently, I'm using POCO objects with one or more dictionaries for indexing. This works excellent when I need to find something by a specific key, but sometimes that isn't the case. As an example, I often need to find an entry within a specific date-time-range. And sometimes I need the entry with the lowest price. Most often, queries look at a few simple keys and one or two other fields at the same time.

Are there any tools, products, libraries (targeting the .NET-framework) that can help me with this? Or do I need to pick up that big dusty old Algorithms book and start looking at search-trees?

An example:

**Trip**

- DepartureCode
- DestinationCode
- HotelCode
- RoomCode
- Date
- Price

I need the query to be something like "get me the least expensive Trip between 2010-03-09 and 2010-03-12 where DepartureCode=LAX DestinationCode=NYC"

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried using a DataView?  The discussion in this question seems to indicate that it performs filters and searches very quickly when compared to the DataGrid: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722095/c-dataset-index

Comment: I think I did try it originally, but I could only create an index on one column at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Lowest price" and "specific date/time range" can both be handled using just a sorted collection and binary search. `SortedList` / `SortedDictionary` (or `SortedSet` if you're using .NET 4.0) probably do everything you need here, with only a fairly small amount of work.

Comment: I'll look into those a bit. I think, however, that they probably won't solve the problem when I need to first look at some keys, and then at a specific range. I've edited the question with an example.

Comment: @andlju: I strongly suspect you're not going to optimise that sort of query very easily without a *lot* of work. After you've applied one (or maybe two) keys - e.g. "find all the trips from LAX to NYC" do you still actually have a lot of trips to work through?

Comment: That is a very good point. In that specific case I still would have a very large amount of trips but the example is somewhat extreme and not very realistic. In most scenarios I'd probably have a more reasonable set of entries left after applying filters on the keys only.

Answer (score 0):

How about the DataSet.Table("YourTable")[.Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/way3dy9w.aspx) method?

```
Dim myRows() as DataRow = myDataSet.Tables("myTable").Select("Date>" & _
    myBeginDate & "AND Date<" & myEndDate)
```

**EDIT:**  From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms971481.aspx)

> DataView Construction
>
> The DataView builds an index for the
>   data in the underlying DataTable when
>   both the DataView is created, and when
>   the Sort, RowFilter or RowStateFilter
>   properties are modified. When creating
>   a DataView object, use the DataView
>   constructor that takes the Sort,
>   RowFilter, and RowStateFilter values
>   as constructor arguments (along with
>   the underlying DataTable). The result
>   is the index is built once. Creating
>   an "empty" DataView and setting the
>   Sort, RowFilter or RowStateFilter
>   properties afterward results in the
>   index being built at least twice.

So if you're wanting to index your DataSet, it looks like a DataView could provide that for you.

Comment: That is a good way of querying (even though I prefer LINQ), but it won't be indexed, right?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it is possible to create more than one index in the dataview, and one index is easy enough for me to create using dictionaries or a sorted list. I would love to be proven wrong on this though, I haven't really researched it that much..